# Prebuilt android avd?

Tags: android

Are there any places where you can download prebuilt android images?

This would be allot easier than trying to guess what settings each device has.

Comment: You mean you want an avd that has exactly the same settings as some particular real device? I don't know if you can do that, but you can use http://developer.android.com/resources/dashboard/platform-versions.html to get an idea of what versions of Android you should support.

Comment: I've thought the same thing. It would be nice if there where a prebuilt avd for ever phone.

Answer (score 0):

I can think of two main reasons why they don't just hand out the settings and specifications of mobile devices:

- Programming for just one case is often a waste of time. Why not do it for any type of screen? If some minor change is to happen you might not even have to tweak your app.
- Copyright and Trade Secret policies by the manufacturers.